# Do we really need a [skill-points] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We apparently have a [skill-points](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skill-points) tag. Is this tag providing us some benefit that the [skills](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skills) tag does not? Do we want to keep it?

Comment: This synonym has been approved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### [Skill-Points] is not a useful tag.

Any question about skill *points* is ultimately a question about *skills*. We have a perfectly good [skills](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skills) tag; that's what we should be using. Having multiple tags that essentially cover the exact same topic makes it harder for users to use the tag system to favorite tags they're experts in, to ignore tags they're not interested in, and to search for questions. We *already* synonym [skill-systems](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skill-systems) and [skill-check](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skill-check) to [skills](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skills) for this exact reason.

We should make [skill-points](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skill-points) a synonym of [skills](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skills); I have initiated the voting for that process [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/skills/synonyms).

Comment: I'm personally a fan of letting the tagsonomy flourish as it will, except where it's causing harm. Is there harm caused/confusion sown that you're seeing here that you can describe/summarize in the post?

Comment: @nitsua60 See edit. In general I think our community has been a little *too* permissive when it comes to tags. The very existence of a tag has a cost to the community, in terms of cognitive load looking at multiple tags on questions, in terms of crowding out other potentially more useful tags. Any tag that doesn't have a demonstrable benefit to counteract that inherent cost should be suspect, IMHO. Honestly, that's a topic for a separate meta question, however.

Comment: Good points, I think. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: The synonym seems to have been approved now.

Comment: @V2Blast Yes, I will be marking this answer as accepted once the required 48 hours has passed.